# PHP mcrypt error with chrome autofill

Tags: php, mcrypt

I have a problem with my mcrypt code:

```
<?php
class Encryption {

    public function encrypt($value){
        $key = 'dfMsnopnM:kNas;ljn46tgskjdnkdnfn';
        if (!$value) {
            return false;
        }
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
        $encrypted_string = trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
        return $encrypted_string;
    }

    public function decrypt($value){
        $key = 'dfMsnopnM:kNas;ljn46tgskjdnkdnfn';
        if (!$value) {
            return false;
        }
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypted_string = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($value), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
        return $decrypted_string;
    } 
}?>
```

Only some strings are decrypted in a wrong way. I can't find any matches between this strings. Only that they all saved in the chrome autofill. Can this be a reason for an error? Or can you find some wrong things in my `Encryption` class?

Comment: You don't seem to have understood how initialisation vectors work. You need to use the same value for decryption that you used for encryption.

Comment: i think i have to use the encrypted value for the decrypt function. Nothing else would make sense. Or do you not mean the `$value` variable?

Comment: I mean the initialisation vector. In both the encrypt and decrypt functions you create a new, random iv and discard it after use. You should only create an iv when encrypting and save it with the encrypted data as you will need it for decryption. And don't use ecb.